# Playing Multiple songs in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mp3

I found a JSFiddle that I really like: http://jsfiddle.net/fYjLx/

The issue is that when I incorporate it into my website, the audio player looks grey and doesn't work.  Here's the code:

JS

```
(function() {
var Mp3Queue = function(container, files) {
    var index = 1;
    if(!container || !container.tagName || container.tagName !== 
'AUDIO')throw 'Invalid container';
    if(!files || !files.length)throw 'Invalid files array';        

    var playNext = function() {
        if(index < files.length) {
            container.src = files[index];
            index += 1;
        } else {
            container.removeEventListener('ended', playNext, false);
        }
    };

    container.addEventListener('ended', playNext);

    container.src = files[0];
};

var container = document.getElementById('container');

new Mp3Queue(container, [
    'file:///C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Music/songs/blue.mp3',
    'file:///C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Music/songs/blue.mp3'
]);
})();

</script>
```

HTML

```
<audio id="container" controls="" autoplay=""></audio>
```

I don't get why it's not working.  My mp3 files are located in a folder called songs, which resides inside a folder called Music, which is on my Desktop.